# Multiselect drop down not selecting multiple value

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to bind the Mutiselect dropdown through Jquery Ajax(Dynamically).

If I will select specific user data then the user-related month will only display which will fetch from the database, and the month dropdown is multiselect which is not able to select multiple values. Tring to do **Cascading**

```
<select id="ddlMonth" name="ddlMonth[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">                              
</select>
```

```
   url: 'cascading.php',
   method: 'post',
   data: 'SBPMonthStudId=' + studid
}).done(function(studentsMonth){
    $('#ddlMonth').append(studentsMonth);
    $('#ddlMonth').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText:'Select Month',
    enableFiltering:true,
    buttonWidth:'100%'
});
```

In this case, Mutiselect Dropdown binding properly but not able to select multiple values

Answer (score 0):

What will the result if you write this code?

```
url: 'cascading.php',
method: 'post',
data: 'SBPMonthStudId=' + studid
}).done(function(studentsMonth){
  $('#ddlMonth').empty();
  $('#ddlMonth').append("<option value='' disabled>--Select Month--</option>");
  $.each(studentsMonth, function(i,item){
    $('#ddlMonth').append('<option value="'+studentsMonth[i].id+'">'+studentsMonth[i].name+'</optoin>');
  });
```